# Не корректно работает атрибут onchange в select

Tags: javascript, html, form

Некорректно работает атрибут onchange. Проблема в том, что при смене первого select не обнуляются другие значения.
Вот код:

```
<form action="https://listryx.com/catalog/" method="get">

  <div class="filter_type">
    <h6>Выберите регион</h6>
    <select name="reg" id="reg" onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }">
      <option value="01">Выберите регион</option>
      <option value="52" selected="">Краснодарский край</option>
      <option value="24">Республика Крым</option>
      <option value="59">Ростовская область</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="filter_type">
    <h6>Город</h6>

    <select name="city" id="reg" onchange="if(this.value != 0) { this.form.submit(); }">
      <option value="01">Выберите город</option>
      <option value="54">Анапа</option>
      <option value="55" selected="">Армавир</option>
      <option value="56">Белореченск</option>
      <option value="57">Геленджик</option>
      <option value="58">Горячий ключ</option>
      <option value="53">Краснодар</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</form>
```

По умолчанию, когда ничего не выбрано, GET параметры такие:
**/catalog/?reg=01&city=01**
При выбранном регионе, город не выбран.
**/catalog/?reg=24&city=01**
То есть, все корректно работает при выборе региона и в последующем города, но если выбран город, а затем выбирается другой регион, то **get параметр city** не становится со значением 01. Другими словами не обнуляется.

**Можно сделать так, что при выборе другого региона, когда выбран уже город значение get параметра city обнулялось на 01?**

Форма расположена на странице: https://listryx.com/catalog/

Comment: Сделать функцию, которая будет проверять `reg != 01 || city != 01` и если нет, то использовать `form.submit();`, не?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const reg = document.getElementById("reg");

const city = document.getElementById("city");

const handler = function() {
  if (this.value != 0) {
    //this.form.submit()
  }
}

reg.addEventListener("change", handler);

reg.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (this.value != 0) {
    city.value = "01";
  }
})

city.addEventListener("change", handler)
```

```html
<form action="https://listryx.com/catalog/" method="get">

  <div class="filter_type">
    <h6>Выберите регион</h6>
    <select name="reg" id="reg">
      <option value="01">Выберите регион</option>
      <option value="52" selected="">Краснодарский край</option>
      <option value="24">Республика Крым</option>
      <option value="59">Ростовская область</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="filter_type">
    <h6>Город</h6>

    <select name="city" id="city">
      <option value="01">Выберите город</option>
      <option value="54">Анапа</option>
      <option value="55" selected="">Армавир</option>
      <option value="56">Белореченск</option>
      <option value="57">Геленджик</option>
      <option value="58">Горячий ключ</option>
      <option value="53">Краснодар</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: через раз только на странице, или в сниппете тоже?

Comment: То есть когда выбран город и регион, меняешь значение региона на другой, id региона в url меняется, а города нет, id города остаётся такой же. Помогите , прошу

Comment: @АнтонВейда это уже отдельный вопрос на тему динамики страницы. если мой ответ решает проблему данного вопроса примите его, и задайте новый по другому вопросу.